There is no "Move to file" refactoring option
I saw VS Code supports Move to file refactoring since version 1.82
But why there is no this option when try to move a TS interface to an existed file?

VS Code: 1.90.2

When choose the TypeScript version of project(4.3.2), the option does not show. After changing the TypeScript version to VS Code's version(5.4.5). The "Move to file refactoring" option appears.
